# Advice needed on cross-sectional time-series with two levels

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis, panel-data, cross-section

As more and more data (e.g., Census, health, labor) becomes available with outcomes at the household-level on randomly selected households each year (or every other year) that can be paired with geographic data (e.g., regional economic conditions, state or local policy choices or housing prices, etc.), we need to build models that I don't think are helped sufficiently by what is known about cross-sectional panel data that is on one level (e.g., a set of countries over time). To put it another way: In the data I am looking at, the households are randomly drawn, but the level at which they cluster (e.g., states/provinces) is a panel (perhaps a complete panel, all states each year). And both the household-level and state-level variables are of interest (e.g., the effect of state unemployment rates on the outcome as they vary over state and by year).

So far, I have seen people deal with this by saying the households (which are not a panel, but are drawn from each geographic area each year) are clustered in a "jurisdiction times year" group, such as "state-years" or "nation-years." For example, you have 50 states and 10 years, so 500 "state-years." However, shouldn't there be some correction (beyond clustering the errors on the state-years, in this example) for the panel nature of the data at the state level? I hope this question makes sense. I think such data will be analyzed more and more, so this is an interesting problem to think about. Thank you for any thoughts.